# How can I get filtred data from a view?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I added a module "Base Candidat" in this module base.candidat I want to open the applications of a specific candidate (that have the same email as the candidate ) I added this function to `base_candidat.py`

```
class base_candidat(osv.osv):
    _columns = { 
        'candidat_name': fields.char('Candidat', size=128, required=True),
        'blacklist': fields.boolean('Blacklist'),
        'email_candidat': fields.char('Email', size=32),
        'mobile': fields.char('Mobile', size=32),
        'priority': fields.selection(AVAILABLE_PRIORITIES, 'Appreciation'),
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsable'),
        'specialite': fields.many2one('base.candidat.specialite', 'Spécialité'),
    }

    def action_get_applications(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        modelDataClass = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
        hrApplicantClass = self.pool.get('hr.applicant')

        model, action_id = modelDataClass.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'hr_recruitment', 'action_hr_job_applications')
        action = self.pool.get(model).read(cr, uid, action_id, context=context)
        email_ids = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context).email_candidat
        candidature_ids = hrApplicantClass.search(cr, uid, [('email_from', '=', email_ids)], context=context)

        action['context'] = {'default_res_model': self._name, 'default_res_id': ids[0]}
        action['domain'] = str([('candidature_ids', 'in', email_ids)])

        return action
```

I have no result . Any suggestions??

Comment: Your question is very unclear in this format. can we see the fields in your model?

Comment: the fields of : class base_candidat(osv.osv):
       _columns = {
        'candidat_name': fields.char('Candidat', size=128, required=True),
        'blacklist': fields.boolean('Blacklist'),
        'email_candidat': fields.char('Email', size=32),
        'mobile': fields.char('Mobile', size=32),
        'priority': fields.selection(AVAILABLE_PRIORITIES, 'Appreciation'),
        'user_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Responsable'),
        'specialite': fields.many2one('base.candidat.specialite', 'Spécialité'),

Answer (score 0):

If I know well, 'action' is an unallowed variable name. If you use it, the program will be not consistent. (Same situation with 'active')
In my opinion, this domain expression is not correct in this line:
`action['domain'] = str([('candidature_ids', 'in', email_ids)])`
Because this mean you model has `candidature_ids` field, but the model has not, so this condition can't satisfied, so you can't see any record, when you use it.
Another problem with your conception, `email_ids` is string (not number, so the variable name is deceptive)and `candidature_ids` is a list of numbers.
In my opinion, you want to write a function field. This is an example code, it may not the optimum performance, but I think it will help you understanding the essential of function field:

```
def _getApplications(self, cr, uid, ids):
    hrApplicantClass = self.pool.get('hr.applicant')

    # get all of candidate
    candidateDatas = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['email_candidat'])

    # collect all of emails
    emails = []
    for candidate in candidateDatas:
        if candidate['email_candidat'] not in emails:
            emails.append(candidate['email_candidat'])

    # get all of relevant applicant
    applicantIds = hrApplicantClass.search(cr, uid, [('email_from', 'in', emails)])
    applicantDatas = hrApplicantClass.read(cr, uid, applicantIds, ['email_from'])

    # pair base_candidat id with application id
    retVal = {}
    for candidate in candidateDatas:
        retVal[candidate['id']] = []
        if not candidate['email_candidat']:
            continue
        else:
            for applicant in applicantDatas:
                if applicant['email_from'] == candidate['email_candidat']:
                    retVal[candidate['id']].append(applicant['id'])

    return retVal

# the field definition
'application_ids': fields.function(_getApplications, method=True, type='one2many', 'Applications')
```

Comment: But when I use the same function without precising the action[domain] I can see all the applications . Do you have any suggestions ? sould I modify the domain or use another way ??Thanks in advance

Comment: My experience is sometimes works it, that's why I said this function will be inconsistent.

Comment: @KhadijaAB What is the relation between base_candidat and hr_applicant? I can't understand what want to filter.

Comment: Well each candidat created in basecandidat could have different applications in hr_applicant for different job_id . So I want in base candidat  for a specific record (candidate) who have a name , email .. I want to see all the applications related to him (who had the same email ) .

Comment: I can't understand all of this method concepts. In my opinion, you want to a function field.